# How to tell when mathematical objects are of different types, e.g. $1$ and $0.5$, or $1$ and $+\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I heard that for the purposes of doing set theory, we adopt the convention that the statement x=y is automatically false if $x, y$ are of different types; for instance, if one is treating sets and numbers as objects of different types, then a set would not be equal to a number.
But what does "type" really mean in mathematics? I am confused about the question of whether $1$ and $+\infty$ are objects of the same type(since they are both extended real numbers) or objects of different types(since $1$ is a real number and $+\infty$ is not). A similar question is, are $1$ and $1/2$ objects of the same type (since they are both real numbers) or objects of different types ($1$ is a natural number but $1/2$ is not)?

I apologize for the language barrier.

Comment: Outside Type theory, what objects are depends on the context of the theory. If the theory is about *natural* numbers, $\dfrac 1 2$ is not an "object" of the domain of the theory; if the theory is about *real* numbers, $1$ and $\dfrac 1 2$ are different objects.

Comment: Context should always supply the answer.  $1=8$ if you are working with residues $\pmod 7$, though $1\neq 8$ if you are working with real numbers.  For example.

Comment: Now I know that if the theory is about natural numbers, 1/2 is not an "object" of the domain of the theory. But if the theory is about real numbers( or extended real numbers), are 1 and 1/2 objects of different types?

Comment: No; in the domain of reals $1$ is a real number, as well as $\dfrac 1 2$ and $\pi$.

Comment: From reading your post and your comment to the only answer currently posted, it seems like your actual question is ***not*** the current title of your post, but rather how to tell when objects are different types, e.g. 1 and 0.5, or 1 and $+\infty$.

Comment: In a formal approach, you may use [Many-sorted logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic) where the "universe" is partitioned in distinct *sorts*

Comment: Not with JavaScript's `==` operator.  But being neither reflexive nor transitive, it's not mathematically an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first look at how formal set theory without any notion of types handles this.

Here, everything is built up starting from the notion of sets, so everything is "really" a set. For example, we typically define $0$ to be the empty set $\emptyset$, $1$ to be $\{0\}$, or $\{\emptyset\}$, and more like this.

We define integers out of the natural numbers, rational numbers out of the integers, and real numbers out of the rationals. There are various ways to do this, usually involving equivalence classes of various equivalence relations.

For example, here is a common way to define the rationals, which I only mention for illustrative purposes. We start with the set $\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\})$: ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of integers with $b\ne 0$. We define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on this set by $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ when $ad = bc$. The equivalence classes of this relation are the rationals: $a/b$ is shorthand for "the equivalence class of $(a,b)$ under $\sim$".

Anyway, once we've done this, there are actually several things all called "$1$". There's $1$ the natural number, constructed as $\{0\}$. There's $1$ the integer. There's $1$ the rational number: as an equivalence class, it consists of all pairs $\{(a,a) : a \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}\}$. There's $1$ the real number, defined using Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts or decimal expansions or sometimes other, weirder things.

When we ask "Is $1 = 1/2$" it is probably clear from context that we are dealing with, say, $1$-the-real-number and $1/2$-the-real-number, and then $1 \ne 1/2$. This happens no matter how we define the real numbers, and so when we're *not* working with foundational things, we don't really care how we define the real numbers.

In practice, we would never ask whether $1$-the-natural number is equal to $1/2$-the-rational number. The answer:

- would depend on the specific way we defined the rational numbers;
- would almost certainly be "no" in this specific case no matter how we did it.

But sometimes we get nonsense "yes" answers if we think about how things look under the hood. The earlier $1 = \{0\}$ is such a nonsense "yes" answer. My favorite nonsense along these lines is "$7$ is a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_open_sets) on $6$".

---

We might want some notion of types to avoid the nonsense "yes" answers. [Formal type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) gets pretty crazy, but somewhat informally you can start by thinking of this as a tag attached to objects to say which thing we mean by them. For example, $1 : \text{real}$ for $1$-the-real-number or $1 : \text{natural}$ for $1$-the-natural-number.

Then, we say that two of these things (called terms) can only be equal if they have the same tag (called a type). For example, $1 : \text{natural}$ and $\{0\} : \text{set-of-naturals}$ are not equal, even though $1$ and $\{0\}$ are equal in set theory without types.

So when we ask if $1 = 1/2$, our first step is, again, to ask: which "$1$" and which "$1/2$" do we mean? (This is usually clear from context.) Then, for example

- $1 : \text{natural}$ and $1/2 : \text{rational}$ are not equal, because they have different types. (This was already almost certainly true without types, but not quite clear because we can construct the rationals in different ways.)
- $1 : \text{real}$ and $1/2 : \text{real}$ are not equal, but they *could be* because they have the same type. We actually have to go and check.

The important thing to remember is that, just as before, we have different terms, $1 : \text{natural}$ and $1 : \text{integer}$ and $1: \text{rational}$ and $1 : \text{real}$, all representing the same concept ("concept" is not a formal notion), but with different types.

Comment: Very good indeed, thanks :-) Maybe it is interesting to note that in "formal set theory - as you say - everything is a set" and thus $=$ is always defined. From this it follows that $1 \text { the natural } \ne 1 \text { the real }$.

Comment: Thanks .This helps a lot. My question now is, can we design these types (tags) freely? For instance, we have only two types "numbers" and "sets", which means that we don't have types such as "naturals","integers" or "rationals", etc.

Comment: @OSCAR "We can design these types freely" is closer to the truth. In formal type theory, there are rules for how to construct types out of other types; we need such rules so that we can prove an object has a certain type. But if you live in a world where only "numbers" (natural numbers?) and "sets" are types, then you're essentially living in a world of untyped set theory (as in the first half of my post) with an extra kind of primitive notion: numbers.

Comment: I like to think of an analogy with programming languages that type theory : ZFC :: higher-order language : assembly.  Under this analogy, for example a CPU typically doesn't know or care whether the value that's in a register is an integer or a pointer; similarly, at the level of ZFC the basic theory doesn't know or care whether you're looking at a real number or an integer, or something else.

Comment: On the programming language side, if you try in assembly to take a value that was meant to be an integer and instead treat it as a pointer, the likely result is a segmentation fault (or nonsense on older CPUs without an MMU).  But in higher-order languages, the likely result is a compilation error.  Similarly, in ZFC if you try to take an integer and treat it as a real number without applying the appropriate canonical embedding function, the likely result is nonsense; whereas in type theories, the likely result is a type error.

Comment: Now I know that if one is treating natural numbers and vectors as objects of different types, then a natural number would not be equal to a vector. But is it true that sometimes we override this convention by identifying objects of one type with some objects of another type, e.g. I think we actually identify each real number x with its counterpart (x,0) in the complex numbers(via isomorphsim). Thus we actually write x=(x,0) in practice. This comment is too long, and I will write another one. Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: Another comment:   I think this causes a trouble. Because we expect this form of substitution property: if x is of type T and y=x, then y is of type T.  But if we write x=(x,0) for each real number x. In particular, 1=(1,0). Then from the substitution property we know that (1,0) is also a real number! But it is not.

Answer (score -1):

When I read this question my initial thought was categorical vs. quantitative. the function, y=x represents a quantitative relationship between two items or variables. Whereas categorically, two objects don't automatically equal each other. In some ways they do but mathematically you can not prove that two objects will always equal each other.

My suggestion to you is, when asking this question, to define whether the object you were thinking of is quantitative or categorical. These are two extremely different subtopics.

Comment: An author writes that in any mathematical theory with types or sorts (such as “natural number”), the property of being any specific sort is automatically a predicate, and that the statement “x=y” is automatically false if one is treating x and y as objects of different types. For instance, if one is treating 3 and { } as objects of different types, then 3≠{ }. My question is, are 1 and 0.5 objects of the same type (since they are both real numbers) or objects of different types (since 1 is a natural number and 0.5 is not)? Sorry for the language barrier.